# Java - jar se freeza desde consola. Funciona bien desde eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8, jvm

Tengo un proyecto que lee constantemente desde un lector de RFID. Realiza una lectura cada 2 o 3 segundos. Está desarrollado con java 8 y eclipse. El problema es el siguiente...si yo genero el jar y lo pongo a correr desde la consola de manera que lea continuamente un chip que está arriba de la antena, el programa corre, lee y graba unos 80 o 90 veces el chip y se freeza...no lee mas aunque tirando un TOP en linux veo que el proceso aun esta corriendo, pero no lee.
Ahora bien, si yo hago lo mismo pero ejecutandose desde Eclipse, eso no pasa...es decir, Eclipse ejecuta mi jar con una configuracion distinta y mas optimizada.
Entonces las consultas son 2...

1. Primera consulta... existe alguna forma de saber/ver como es la configuración que utiliza eclipse para lanzar mi jar?.
2. Que es lo que estaria mal en la forma en que yo lanzo desde la consola mi jar?.

La orden que uso para lanzar el jar es la siguiente:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/bin/java -jar -server -Xms3G -Xmx3G -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/java_error_client.log -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/java_heapdump_client.log -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled  -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit -Duser.timezone=GMT-3 /home/solutraz/linearoca/ClientLauncher.jar
```

Cuando tiro el siguiente comando (sudo update-alternatives --config java) por consola para ver que versiones de java instaladas tengo, me dà lo siguiente:

```
Existe 1 opción para la alternativa java (que provee /usr/bin/java).

  Selección   Ruta                                     Prioridad  Estado
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      modo automático
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      modo manual
```

Cabe aclarar que la PC donde corre tiene 4GB de ram.
Gracias!

Comment: ¿tienes solo Java 8 en tu maquina no tienes instalado otro JDK aparte?

Comment: Solo java 8 tengo instalado

Comment: @AlvaroC. me quede con la duda entonces prendi la pc y tire el siguiente comando: sudo update-alternatives --config java y me sale lo siguiente: que tengo instalado 2, pero son el mismo, uno en modo automatico y el otro en modo manual. Voy a editar la pregunta y poner esto porque en el comentario no me deja.

Comment: Como solo se aprecia una versión de Java te pregunto ahora por la salida del ps -fea cuando ejecutas desde eclipse y cuando ejecutas desde la linea de comandos.